# how to get around the firewall when connecting to the remote server

Tags: ssh, firewall

I want to connect to a remote computer and start Jupyter notebook on the remote computer. Every time I try to connect to jupyter notebook there is an error. When I turn off my firewall the jupyter notebook works. Is there any way to not turn off the firewall and get around this?

My computer has windows and the remote computer has ubuntu installed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that you are turning off the firewall on your client machine, you need to add a outbound rule to allow a SSH connection.
If you are using Windows firewall then you can use the following command to add a outbound rule via command-line (**CHANGE THE PORT YOU ARE USING FOR SSH ACCORDINGLY**): 
`netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="Open SSH Port 22" dir=in action=allow protocol=TCP localport=22 remoteip=any` as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68594389/16326352) by [Krypton Razer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7764243/krypton-razer).

Alternatively you can also add this rule via GUI as stated in the [documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/windows-firewall/create-an-outbound-port-rule).

Comment: No I am turning off the windows firewall.